# is it possible to calculate the applicationIconBadgeNumber when the localNotification is called

Tags: ios, push-notification

I know how to schedule a localNotification and set the applicationIconBadgeNumber when the localNotification is pushed:

```
- (void) scheduleNotificationOn:(NSDate*) fireDate
                            text:(NSString*) alertText
                            action:(NSString*) alertAction
                             sound:(NSString*) soundfileName
                       launchImage:(NSString*) launchImage 
                           andInfo:(NSDictionary*) userInfo
{

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;

    ....

    self.badgeCount ++;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = self.badgeCount;         

    // Schedule it with the app
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [localNotification release];
}
```

As the code shows, applicationIconBadgeNumber is set before the localNotification is called. I want to know is it possible to calculate the applicationIconBadgeNumber when the localNotification is called and display it nearby the app icon?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Unless your app is running in foreground that you can catch the fire of local notification.